# It feels interesting?

Tags: adjectives, present-participles

"It feels interesting", Does it make sense?

I am accustomed to using "feel + Adjective" and "feel like + Noun" forms.

but I wonder if it could be right to use "feel + Present-participle(as an adjective)".

Logically, it could be, but I've hardly seen it before.

Googling "it feels interesting", I found out an article using the sentence.

link: http://www.newsworks.org.uk/news-and-opinion/Page-265/trinity-mirror-to-launch-national-newspapers-the-new-day

If you feel it sounds a little impolite, it'll be because I'm not a native English speaker. So, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Sounded just fine, I understood perfectly. :)

Answer (score 1):

"It feels interesting" would make sense if you where describing something being touched.

"It seems interesting" would be used when describing a thought, or idea.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please add sources to your answer. Have a look at he [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers.

Answer (score 0):

When you use 'feels' in this way. This is known as a mental state verb. Other common mental state verbs are:

> now, think, learn, understand, perceive, guess, recognize, notice,
>   want, wish, hope, decide, expect, remember, forget, imagine, and
>   believe.

Mental state verbs have propositional meanings. Referring to the fact the person using the verb is undergoing a mental process / experience. So you can use feel with any mental state you can experience, such as interested, or you can feel something is interesting, (in the present continuous tense you speak of) meaning it is a mental state you are experiencing now.

To use feels instead of feel though, I believe it would only make sense like this: -

> X feels Y is interesting

Where you are referring to the object of interest.

You can read more about mental state verbs [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Mental-state-Verb.htm)